# Why is this is undefined when mocking event in React unit testing, using sinon.spy to mock function and enzyme.shallow render for React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, sinon, enzyme

Whenever I try to simulate an event where I am passing the `event` object, I am getting that `this` is `undefined`.

```
const onBlur = sinon.spy(Input.prototype.handleBlur);
const wrapper = shallow(<Input handleBlur={onBlur} />);
//...
wrapper.find('input').simulate('blur', { target: {value: ''} });
```

Inside of the `handleBlur` method, `this` is undefined.  However, if I decide not to mock the `event` object, then event is undefined.

Also, I tried using `mount` instead:

`const wrapper = shallow(<Input handleBlur={onBlur} />);`

But, it's the same thing.  However, I couldn't even get to that point until I updated the npm libraries.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
const onBlur = sinon.spy(Input.prototype, "handleBlur");
```

instead

```
const onBlur = sinon.spy(Input.prototype.handleBlur);
```